# Where are my mistakes in my scrapy codes?

Tags: web, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl a website via scrapy but my codes come up with an error.
I have tried to use xpath but it seems I can not define the div class in the web site.

The following code raises an error on `("h2 ::text").extract()`.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from artistlist.items import ArtistlistItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "artistlist"
    allowed_domains = ["baltictriennial13.org"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.baltictriennial13.org/artist/caroline-achaintre/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='artist']")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = ArtistlistItem()
            item["artist"] = titles.select("h2 ::text").extract()
            item["biograpy"] = titles.select("p::text").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

I want to crawl the web site and store the data in a .csv file.

Comment: please share your error message :)

Comment: You can see the error msg below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is using of `.select` instead of `.css`. Here is what do you need but I'm not sure about `titles` part (may be you need it on other pages):

```
def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.xpath("//div[@class='artist']")
    # items = []
    for title in titles:
        item = ArtistlistItem()
        item["artist"] = title.css("h2::text").get()
        item["biograpy"] = title.css("p::text").get()
        # items.append(item)
        yield item
```

Comment: thank you for the hints. Actually, when I revise the codes and put "response.css", it gave me what I wanted to see.

Comment: these are the revised codes: def parse(self, response):
        #hxs = Selector(response)
        titles = response.xpath("//div[@class='btText']")
        #items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = ArtistlistItem()
            item['artist'] = response.css('h2 ::text').extract()
            item['biography'] = response.css('p::text').extract()
            #items.append(item)
            yield item
        #return items

Answer (score -1):

try to remove the space in `h2 ::text --> h2::text`. If that doesn't work try `h2/text()`

Comment: I tried both but neither of them worked for me. I guess there might be problem in defining div class.

Comment: Error msg:019-07-14 15:58:09 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/erdal/artistlist/artistlist/spiders/test.py:16: ScrapyDeprecationWarning:Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead.
  item["artist"] = titles.select("h2/text()").extract()

2019-07-14 15:58:09 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/erdal/artistlist/artistlist/spiders/test.py:17: ScrapyDeprecationWarning:Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead.
  item["biograpy"] = titles.select("p/text()").extract()

Comment: well that brings us a bit closer :) you can do as the warning message says and use xpath instead of select.